# Creality CR 6 SE Z-axis issue

Tags: z-axis, creality-cr-6

My new Creality CR6 SE was doing good but suddenly its Z-Axis (head extruder) randomly sometimes stays above the required configurations and sometimes below.

For example after auto leveling when I adjust the Z-axis with paper under it, it aligns fine at 0.20 mm after print if I start next print at same Z-axis configurations 0.20 mm randomly some time it gets below the past configurations and the extruder is very close to the bed or even badly touching the bed.

But sometime after the next print, it's above the bed that filament stays around and does not stick with the bed.

So the solution is every time I start new printing I have to level Z-axis, after trying it a lot, it is always best set at 0.20 mm.

I have to set the Z-Axis each time I print; how can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you saying you have to level the bed each time you print, or did I misunderstand? Leveling every time is pretty standard.

Comment: What is the question? You seem to have posted an issue, along with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have to level the bed each time you print, or did I misunderstand?

Leveling every time is pretty standard.

The question appears to be "my bed doesn't stay level. What's wrong?". So my answer is, "That's normal, nothing's wrong."